# Jqgrid Toolbar Filteration Dropdown and Min Max Range

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a Free JqGrid MVC version.So this question based on Toolbar filteration(Searching).
In this item grid that consist `Item Name` it's a string filed and it's filteration is working properly.
For the filed of `Item Condition` data comes as `N` or `O` so there i need a **Dropdown** there.
For the `Item Weight` it comes as a `Integers` and there i need to filter from `Range` like Min/Max

Here i have tried like this,

```
    <div id="item_grid_main" class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
@(Html.jqGrid("JQItemGrid")
.setCaption(null)
.setDataType(Enums.jqGridDataTypes.local)
//some items removed.
.setRowNum(int.MaxValue)
.setViewRecords(true)
.setNavSearch(true)
.setNavAdd(true)
.setNavEdit(true)
.setGridView(true)
.setSearchToolbar(true)
.setSearchOnEnter(false)
.setSortOrder(Enums.SortOrder.desc)
.setData(Json.Encode(Model.gridModel))

.addColumns(new List<jqGridColumn>() {
            new jqGridColumn("ItemId").setLabel("Item Id").setHidden(true).setKey(true),
            new jqGridColumn("ItemName").setLabel("Item Name").setHidden(false).setWidth(50).setSortable(true),
            new jqGridColumn("ItemCondition").setLabel("Item Condition").setHidden(false).setWidth(50).setSortable(true).setSearchType(Enums.SearchType.select),
            new jqGridColumn("ItemWeight").setLabel("Item Weight").setHidden(false).setWidth(50).setSortable(true),

}).Render()
    )
            </div>
        </div>
```

> In this grid basically i need to Filter the Item Condition as a N or O and Filter Item Weight as like Range Min/Max